# Combination Outlet/Switch - Two Wires Only

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle

I want to replace my regular bathroom lightswitch with a combo outlet/switch. Seems the wirebox only has 2 wires but i do see a 'mysterious' third wire in the back that is not connected to anything there. All videos i've viewed about installing combo outlet/switch requires 3 or more wires. My apartment building was built in the 1940s and our Super said the building wasn't wired with ground.

Anyone know if installing combo outlet/switch is a possibility with the wiring I have now?

Thanks!!

[image: wiring]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo that shows the bottom of the box please? Something interesting is going on here...

Comment: You apartment *appears* to be wired with conduit, which is also ground...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - photo of bottom of box posted. i believe that's just a bunch of broken up old plaster/rocks.

Comment: @Ecnerwal - is that the weird looking wired with a pattern instead of a solid color? That wire doesn't seem to be used for anything in this box.

Comment: There aren't any holes in the bottom right of the box the weird wire could be extending out of I take it?

Comment: Also, can you post a photo that clearly shows the top left of the box please?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - photo of top left posted. The weird wire is coming out it. i took it out of the box and took pic of that too. Seems connected to another wire with same pattern

Comment: @Michael -- one other detail -- does the circuit this light is on serve other things, or just this bathroom?  And does this bathroom not already have a receptacle in it?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - just the bathroom. there was one receptacle attached to the wirebox for the light fixture above sink. i recently replaced the light fixture with a new one that does not have a receptacle because i wanted to install the combo outlet/light switch.

Comment: You'll need to use a GFCI switch-recep combo **which also has a "self-grounding" feature** which has an extra scraper blade that contacts the screw threads, so it reliably picks up ground contact that way.   That feature isn't needed for switches, but it is for receptacles.  I don't see a practical way to attach a ground wire to the metal box.

Answer (score 3):

### That weird wire is your neutral, and the conduit's your ground

Your building was wired using what appears to be cloth-covered wires in metal *conduit*.  This would not be atypical for a large or high-rise building in the 1940s, especially in an urban area with strict building codes.  The mottled pattern you see on the wires in the back of the box is a simple fact of aging, by the way -- those two wires were originally white, and still are much lighter than the other wires in the box.  As a result, we know that those two "weird" wires are actually white *neutral* wires, with power coming in from the top left and going to an in-line splice with a pigtail to the switch and an always-hot heading off to the top right, where the switched-hot also departs the box.  Furthermore, since we have metal conduit here (from the lack of paper packing or jacketing peeking through), we know that the conduit itself provides grounding here.

As a result of that, and since this circuit serves only this bathroom, we are clear to install a GFCI/switch combo receptacle here.  You'll have to cut the existing splice in the neutral out and add a neutral pigtail to do this, though, as well as cutting out the existing pigtail splice in the hots and replacing it with a new splice and pigtail that also joins one of the switch wires into the bundle of hots.  The other switch lead gets connected to the switched-hot then, and the hot and neutral pigtails we created land on their respective LINE terminals on the GFCI.  The LOAD terminals stay unused, and you can either use a grounding pigtail to connect the GFCI's ground screw to a 10-32 ground screw driven into the back of the box, or use a *self-grounding* GFCI/switch combo that's listed for grounding through the mounting screws.

Comment: I posted the switch/receptacle combo I have. Not sure if it's GFCI. Can I use the one I have to install? If so, could you explain which wires would need to go to which screws?

Comment: @Michael -- it's not a GFCI, unfortunately, and you need it to be since you're putting this in a bathroom

Comment: So basically in a nutshell:

1. Combine the white neutral wires with another white neutral wire creating 1 neutral wire?


2. Combine the red and black hot wires with another hot wire together creating 1 hot wire?


3. The 1 neutral wire and 1 hot wire are to be placed in their line terminals?


Is grounding necessary?

Comment: @Michael -- use a self-grounding type GFCI/switch combo.  if you can't find one, you'll need to drive a Garvin GSST into the back of the box then run a pigtail to that screw from the ground screw on the GFCI/switch

Comment: Ok thanks! Am I correct with my novice wiring explanation or am i about to blow up my apartment?

Comment: @Michael -- your explanation looks correct save for not having the switch pigtails included

Comment: – i've uploaded a diagram of what I think needs to be done according to your instructions. However, I am confused about the switch pigtail. Are you saying there should be another wire? Can you please let me know what is missing from the uploaded diagram?

Comment: @Michael -- actually, my prior comment was off.  the red/black hot wires need to connect to one of the wires that connects to the switch, not to the bundle of always-hot wires bringing power into the box. The other switch wire connects to that always-hot bundle, then -- what you're missing here is that GFCI/switch combos have a pair of pigtail leads for the switch connections (due to not having enough room for all the terminal screws they'd need otherwise)

Comment: @Michael -- [have the instruction sheet for a GFCI/switch](https://www.leviton.com/en/docs/GFSW1_Instruction_Sheet_English.pdf) if that helps you at all